# Intersection of two vectors

Tags: opencv

I need to get the intersection of two vectors such that:

```
vector<int> a{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8};
vector<int> b{2 4 6 8 10 12};
```

result should be:

```
vector<int> c{2 4 6 8}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Is that a `std::vector` or an OpenCV-specific type?  If it's a `std::vector` and your elements are sorted look at doing `#include <algorithm>` and [std::merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/).

Comment: check [this][1] post which how to use intersection of vector

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483663/vector-intersection-in-c

Comment: It's better to use std::set take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/